# How to use nedit using Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm new to using Ubuntu (just started using it a couple of days ago). 
I installed NEdit using the following commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nedit

When I type nedit in Ubuntu however, I get the following error:

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Hi and welcome at SO. I think there is a better place for your question (askubuntu.com).

Comment: you can ask this Question at [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Like others said, your question is a better fit for [ubuntu.se]. Also, there are many possible reasons for a segfault, so it is unlikely [ubuntu.se] can figure this out. Your best bet is to ask the devs.